# Inheritance and Printing in Bank account in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

This is a section from my bank account code, i am new to OOP and have added some inheritance to my code, the trouble i am having is with printing the balance with interest, when i print it I get the same value as the regular balance without interest, give your insight.

```
from random import randint


class BankAccount(object):
    def __init__(self, initial_balance=0):
        self.balance = initial_balance
    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount       
    def get_balance(self, initial_balance, rate):
        return self.get_balance() * self._rate

class BankAccountWithInterest(BankAccount):
  def __init__(self, initial_balance=0, rate=0.1):
     BankAccount.__init__(self, initial_balance)
     self._rate = rate           
  def interest(self):
     return self.balance * self._rate


balance = (randint(100, 500))
my_account = BankAccount(balance)
my_interest = BankAccountWithInterest(balance)
print(my_account.balance)
print(my_interest.balance)
```

Comment: You aren't calling the interest method. If you don't call that method then its never going to apply the value of your interest to your balance.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem.. but since you are new to OOP.. I would suggest you don't need `BankAccountWithInterest` and thus inheritance. Just have a interest calculation method in `BankAccount` and pass in `0` for accounts where interest is not applicable.

Comment: the project i am doing specifically asks for inheritance, but i managed to get it working so its fine

Answer (score 0):

```
print(my_interest.balance + my_interest.interest())
```

Seems to return what you expect.

```
my_interest.balance = my_interest.balance + my_interest.interest()
print(my_interest.balance)
```

Will also update the balance with the added interest.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems here, the main one being that you don't ever apply (call) the interest function, which is why you get the same balance for both. You should do:

```
print(my_account.balance)
print(my_interest.balance + my_interest.interest())
```

I would also recommend changing `self._rate` to `rate` in the `get_balance` method, otherwise you may get an error when you call `get_balance` and it tries to access self._rate. You should also have it return `self.balance` or `self.balance + rate` otherwise you are getting an infinite loop.